# Python - Dividir palavras delimitada por espaço em branco ou colchete

Tags: python, regex

Tenho uma string com varias palavras dentro, algumas palavras estão separadas por espaço, mas algumas são palavras composta e estão protegidas por colchete.

EX:

string = "Goiânia Vitória Brasília [Campo Grande] Fortaleza [São Paulo] Manaus"

Preciso separar estas palavras, retornando uma lista com elas separadas.

EX de saída:

"Goiânia"

"Vitória"

"Brasília"

"Campo Grande"

"Fortaleza"

"São Paulo"

"Manaus"

Como crio uma expressão regular que faz isso em python?

Comment: William, atento a localidades em que o apóstrofo faz parte da denominação. Por exemplo, Santa Bárbara d'Oeste.

Comment: William, já que editou a pergunta, por quê não aproveita e responde o comentário do José sobre cidades que possuem nomes compostos e com apóstrofo? O que deve acontecer nesse caso, pois você teria algo como `"'Santa Bárbara d'Oeste'"`? Não seria interessante obter o nome completo da cidade? Esse apóstrofo no nome seria tratado de alguma forma?

Comment: Obrigado José e Anderson, acho que o ideal seria mudar em vez de usar apóstrofo seria bom definir como delimitador de palavras composta chaves ou colchetes, ficando algo assim. EX: string="Goiânia Vitória Brasília [Campo Grande] Fortaleza [São Paulo] Manaus". Vou atualizar a pergunta!

Comment: Adicionei `[Santa Bárbara d'Oeste]` no case da resposta, veja se este regex lhe ajuda `\[(.*?)\]|(\S+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, a ideia basicamente é trabalhar com agrupamentos.

O primeiro passo é identificar o padrão dos dados para montar o regex adequado.

Com base nas informações fornecidas identifiquei o seguinte padrão:

```
\[(.*?)\]|(\S+)
```

Basicamente é um agrupamento qualquer entre [], ou (|) um agrupamento qualquer de palavras.

Você pode testar o regex em tempo real no [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/gsSsgSXNoz),

Este regex basicamente vai lhe retornar caso de match no grupamento 1 os nomes entre [], e no grupamento 2 as outras palavras.

Utilizando a linguagem de programação python3 ficaria algo como:

```
import re
text = """Goiânia Vitória Brasília [Campo Grande] Fortaleza [São Paulo] Manaus [Santa Bárbara d'Oeste]"""
regex = re.compile('\[(.*?)\]|(\S+)')
matches = regex.finditer(text)
for match in matches:
    if(match.group(1) is None):
        print(match.group(2))
    else:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/gyHkLe)

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou e consegui adaptar as minha necessidades.